# Select N random records in SQL Server without repetition

Tags: sql, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate, random, unique

How do I select N random records from a table at a time without repetition of records previously returned by the same operation?

An obvious solution is:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM
MyTable
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM PreviouslyReturned)
ORDER BY newid()
```

But wouldn't that be really inefficient as MyTable starts to grow?

I have a long list of records and I require five records at a time for a turn-based game without repeating any of the records already pulled for the given game. Since I know approximately how many turns will take place, I could select a random sample before the game starts that is significantly large, but I would rather it be "dynamic". I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966154/how-to-select-random-unique-records-on-each-execution-of-the-sql-query), which uses a random seed with MySQL.

Eventually there will be so many records that repetition won't be an issue (records >> N), but until then, I need records to be unique. On a sidenote, I use Fluent NHibernate for my persistence layer; perhaps NHibernate has some feature which allows this.

Comment: "Eventually there will be so many records that repetition won't be an issue." I don't know how you can make that statement unless you can guarantee that your pseudo random number generator will never give you the same value twice in a row.

Comment: @Jim, I mean that a repeat once in a blue moon is not that big a deal for my application.

Comment: Your intuition might be wrong here, [Birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Answer (score 2):

> without repeating any of the records

That's not called *selecting random records* among programmers. Values selected randomly repeat more often than you think, and in fact counting the number and length of repeats is one way statisticians detect cheating.

What you're looking for is called a *shuffle*. Shuffling randomizes the order of a finite set of things, like cards or keys. (Randomizing the order of rows doesn't mean the same thing as selecting random rows.)

In your case, plan to store the set of keys already used for each user. Select a random set of rows that aren't already in that set. There are several ways to store each random set of rows (keys); make sure you can tell which one is the *last* or *current* set.

Comment: yes, you're right. It's a shuffle. If I have several thousand rows and I've pulled 100 (which I do keep track of), then each subsequent select would need a `WHERE NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Used_Rows)` clause, which seems really inefficient. Or is it?

Comment: There's more than one way to express `WHERE NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Used_Rows)`. SQL Server 2005+ supports `EXCEPT`, for example. Different expressions might give you different execution plans. If there's a real performance problem with just a few thousand rows, it's probably going to be in selecting random rows in the first place, not in filtering by the values in Used_Rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())
```

There's a related question that goes into detail on the semantics of random shuffle selection here : 
[Random select is not always returning a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035808/random-select-is-not-always-returning-a-single-row/3036038#3036038)

SQL Server evaluates RAND once per query, which means that the mySQL trick will not work anyway.

Edit: this is also adequate

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

I read your updated question and have another suggestion:
Create an indexed view on

```
SELECT mt.*
FROM MyTable mt
LEFT JOIN PreviouslyReturned pr ON mt.Id = pr.Id
WHERE pr.Id Is NULL
```

or something similar

Then

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM YOUR_INDEXED_VIEW
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Why would wrapping `NEWID()` in `CHECKSUM(...)` affect the shuffling of the rows other than changing the order? Does the output of CHECKSUM vary between sessions or queries for the same input?

Comment: @FreshCode: It wouldn't. CHECKSUM is inconsequential in this case. It actually made it into the answer by accident. ORDER BY NEWID() will do the trick alone. MS SQL evaluates RAND() once per query, NEWID() once per row, which is the important bit. In regards to CHECKSUM varying between sessions, you may wanna ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @Chris, I am aware that each sampling is independent and may returns rows returned by a prior sampling. I have edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: @Chris, thanks. Isn't a `LEFT JOIN with a WHERE pr.Id is NULL` equivalent to a `WHERE NOT IN( ... )`?

Comment: @FreshCode: Not always. Beware of WHERE NOT IN behaviour when NULLs are invloved. i.e. WHERE Id NOT IN (1,2,NULL,etc) I'd compare execution plans either way ... check LEFT JOIN against NOT IN against EXCEPT.

Answer (score 0):

You could just store all primary keys of your table in a second table, select randomly from this one (retrieving the associated rows from the original table) and delete them after selection (from the auxiliary table, of course).

I would expect this way to be more efficient than storing the keys already used and constructing a `WHERE NOR IN` (resp. `EXCEPT`) clause (deleting should be approximately as performant as inserting, and selecting should work significantely faster without an additional clause). But of course this would have to be proved (by profiling ...)

Selecting five random ids should work fine using the approach in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966154/how-to-select-random-unique-records-on-each-execution-of-the-sql-query) you've cited.

Comment: I suppose I could have a global "shuffle" table which is replenished when empty, but inserting new records if the original data changed would be a chore.